# VB6 - Cannot read Excel file to its entirety

Tags: excel, file, vb6, xls

No matter what method I try (currently I'm using Scripting.FileSystemObject) I just cannot read this XLS file properly. Here's my code (I don't want to read the cells, I want to read the file as if it was a text file)

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim f As File
Dim fsoStream As TextStream
Dim strLine As String
Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ara\DOSYA.xls")

Set fsoStream = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

Do While Not fsoStream.AtEndOfStream
     strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
     Text1.Text = Text1.Text & strLine
Loop

fsoStream.Close
Set fsoStream = Nothing
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

All I'm getting is the first 5-6 characters of the file and then a little more gibberish and that's it. If I open it in Excel it works fine.

Comment: What's the purpose of reading Excel file contents as TEXT - not BINARY - data?

Comment: Not quite sure what the difference is but ideally I would want to see the same things I would see if I opened it in a hex editor or notepad.

Comment: Hmmmm.......... that's how Excel file looks in Notepad-similar tool when opened as "text" file: http://floomby.ru/s1/9ZXJr - are you sure you want read that content instead of actual Excel cells values?

Comment: Yes, well technically the values inside the cells in XLS files are still in that mess. If I were to read the cells, I would have an infinite number of cells to go through since I am not to know which cells are occupied.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to reveal the purpose of such strange approach for Excel reading: in case you need some range of cells on the sheet - there are pretty simple native VBA methods that wil allow to read as many cells as you wish - or even ALL of them without knowing the actual range, and without any infinite loops.

Comment: My aim is to search for a specific string (word, number anything) in a bunch of XLS and DOC files. It could be anywhere in the document. The code needs to retrieve the ones that include that string.

Comment: You can't display binary data in a VB textbox control. You can't even safely read it as text. In answer to why only a few bytes appear, the textbox truncates at teh first null character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim you want to achieve (from the comments under question) is not a problem - below is a quick piece of code I generated on the fly mostly using parts from macro-recorder:

```
Sub SearchString()

Dim LookupString As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim SearchResult As Range
Dim MatchString As Boolean

Dim SourceFolder As String
Dim FileName As String

SourceFolder = "D:\DOCUMENTS\" 'Trailing "\" is required
LookupString = "abc"

FileName = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.xls?") 'Extension may be set using wildcards
Do While FileName <> ""

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Workbooks.Open (SourceFolder & FileName)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MatchString = False

For Each WS In Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets

    Set SearchResult = WS.Cells.Find(What:=LookupString, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then MatchString = True

Next WS

If MatchString = True Then MsgBox "File: " & Chr(34) & FileName & Chr(34) & vbNewLine & "has " & Chr(34) & LookupString & Chr(34) & " string."

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(FileName).Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

FileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

This will loop trough all types of Excel files put in the `SourceFolder` and will show a message in case defined string is found. The amount of sheets in the book and their hidden / visible status do not matter.

Sample file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipmztbz6vu7y4qf/FilesLookupString.xlsm

I'm pretty sure you'll be able to adapt this for DOC files as well: just use macro-recorder for parts that may differ, e.g. search. Good luck!

In case you're determined to read Excel file contents as "binary-like" (however I'd recommend NOT to do that) - look toward `ADODB.Stream` object.

Comment: That's a great answer and it does indeed work if I open it in excel. I was hoping to make this into a more visual interface using VB6, though. I have a piece of code now that searches the XLS file but has some weird quirks such as with some files, an excel dialog pops up asking you if you want to save or not and unless you click it gets stuck. Secondly I'm not sure how I can iterate through different sheets in one excel document.

Comment: @user1784397 Answers for all your questions are in my code - simply try to understand which part does this or that job. After doing that you'll be proud of yourself and won't be stuck anymore for any similar tasks. That's how I learned VBA - 4 months ago I could not even understand a WORD from the above code)))